# Registering SelectedIndexChanged event on GridView Row

Tags: asp.net, gridview, postback

I'm registering a postback event for each row in an ASP.NET GridView.

```
protected void gvLRR_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {

    if (cs == null)
      cs = Page.ClientScript;

    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", 
      cs.GetPostBackEventReference((GridView)sender, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));
  }
}
```

The event that is called upon the user clicking a row is the SelectedIndexChanged of the GridView gvLRR.

**PROBLEM:**
All of this works just fine so long as I set the page directive EnableEventValidation to false, but if I do not set it to false then the page blows up when the user clicks on a row in the GridView. However, I see this as a bit of a hack, because I shouldn't have to disable event validation just to get postback events to work when clicking upon a GridView row. So is there a better way to go about doing this? Can I somehow register postback events for a row click and somehow manage to have event validation enabled still?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: The code you posted is OnRowDatabound. Don't you need a SelectedIndexChanged event?

Comment: He used the OnRowDatabound event to assign dynamically a call to the GridView event SelectedIndexChanged. He could have stated the reason tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While searching the net, I found this ... [click row on gridview and trigger postback c#](http://forums.asp.net/t/1666327.aspx/1?click%20row%20on%20gridview%20and%20trigger%20postback%20c%20)

HTH :)

Comment: That's what I was looking for! I'd googled it myself but hadn't come up with anything specific to what I was doing, but what you found is what I needed. Thanks again.